# call logs of particular number

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentresolver, calllog

i want to display call logs of particular caller the number is getting from another activity but query which i tried not working please give solution. code which are in comments are what i tried. 
thanks

```
public class CallLogs extends Activity {

     TextView tv,tv2;
     //ListView lv;
     //SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_logs);        
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    getCallDetails();
    String phone = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Phone");
    tv2.setText(phone);
}

    private void getCallDetails() {
      String phone = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Phone");
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
      /* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
      Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
        /*CallLog.Calls.NUMBER+" = ?"*/null,/*new String[]{phone}*/null, strOrder);
      int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
      int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
      int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
      int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
      sb.append("Call Log :");
      while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
       String phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
       String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
       String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
       Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
       String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
       String callType = null;
       int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
       switch (callcode) {
       case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
        callType = "Outgoing";
        break;
       case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
        callType = "Incoming";
        break;
       case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
        callType = "Missed";
        break;
       }
       sb.append("Phone Number: " + phNum + " \nCall Type:"
       + callType + " \nCall Date: " + callDate
      + " \nCall duration in sec : " + callDuration);
      sb.append("\n--------------------------");

      // adapter = new   SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.custcontview,managedCursor,new         String[]{"NUMBER","TYPE","DATE","DURATION"},new int[] {R.id.ccontNo,R.id.ccontName,R.id.ccontType,R.id.textView1});
      }
      tv.setText(sb);
     // lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    //  managedCursor.close();

     }

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

Use the following code to retreive log

```
public void getLogsByNumber(String[] strNumber ) {   
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ? ", strNumber , "");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst ()) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext ()) {
            String id = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (CallLog.Calls._ID));
            String number = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
            String name = cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));

        }

      }

}
```

Comment: I modified this line
  Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ? ", new String[]{phone}, strOrder);

but get error this(logcat):
01-16 03:35:56.782: E/AndroidRuntime(824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.econtact/com.example.econtact.CallLogs}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
01-16 03:35:56.782: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

Comment: "The bind value" apparently refers to the selectionArgs for the selection, that you insert into query(). If such a selArgs value is null,

Comment: probably your "strOrder" is null or "phone" is null

Comment: I dont know what are you doing, but I am getting records

Comment: i got nothing in cursor